# Использование Lombok

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, lombok

Пишу веб-приложение и при объявлении сущностей использую ломбок. Приложение компилируется и работает исправно, но в коде, где происходит работа с сущностями idea все подчеркивает и считает ошибкой. Например, на `jsp` странице вывожу в цикле информацию о сущности - не видит поля объекта. В контроллере подчеркивает создание объекта(конструкторы).
Можно как-то подавить эти ошибки, т.к. они возникают из-за того, что ломбок еще не отработал?
Код сущности:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;
    @Column(name = "password")
    String password;
    @Column(name = "email")
    String email;

    public User(String name, String password, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: что используете для сборки проекта? покажите конфиг градла или мавена

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij